# oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-28547

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, oracle, pecl

I have this connection string on an older server which works fine and connects to a remote oracle server.

On this new server I installed oracle instant client simple and devel and php pecl oci8. Below is the screenshot of the oci8.

Here is the code I use to connect

```
$db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" . $ORACLE_HOST . ")(PORT=" . $ORACLE_PORT . ")))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=" . $ORACLE_DB . ")))";
$this->dbh = oci_connect($ORACLE_USER, $ORACLE_PASS, $db);
```

But when I try to connect to oracle I get this error

```
oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-28547
```

If I type a random hostname I get `ORA-12154` error which makes sense
If I type a random SID I get `ORA-12514` error which makes sense
If I type a random port I get `ORA-12545` error which makes sense
If I `nc` the server and port I get this result

```
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.10.40.21:1521.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.02 seconds.
```

System I use is Centos 7 64bit, php 5.6

Anyone has any idea why this might happen?

[image]

Comment: What version of Oracle? Have you tried `TNSPING` yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems even though `phpinfo` can detect oracle client version 18.5 but it fails to get `ORACLE_HOME` directory

If you only set

```
SetEnv ORACLE_HOME "/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib"
```

in client's virtual host config file

```
/etc/httpd/conf/sites-available/client.vhost
```

This adds `ORACLE_HOME` to `PHP Variables` only which has **NO EFFECT** fixing the problem

**Instead**

You need to add

```
env[ORACLE_HOME] = /usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib
```

in client's `php-fpm` config file

```
/etc/php-fpm.d/client.conf
```

This adds `ORACLE_HOME` under both `PHP Variables` and `Environment` which fixes the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your `sqlnet.ora` set up for easy connect?  (Located in `$ORACLE_HOME//network/admin`) Check out [Oracle Net Services documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/naming.htm#NETAG1125) on setting it up; you should have a line there similar to:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(ezconnect, tnsnames)
```

Also see this [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/trouble.htm#NETAG016).

Answer (score 0):

You've got two problems:

- Oracle can't get the correct translation for error ORA-28547. This is probably because of a incorrect installation/configuration. Is your `echo $ORACLE_HOME` set?
- But the real problem is the error ORA-28547 which is "connection to server failed", probably Oracle Net admin error".